# Snowflake: Execute multiple SQL queries (contain only SELECT statements) at once in Prod env without snowSQL

Tags: sql, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Background:

We ran a custom build SQL for checking Integrity in Dimension and Fact tables. This was performed in Toad for Oracle by using 'Execute as a Script' task feature. It ran all SQL statements (approx. 100 SQL scripts) and spooled the Results into a file and place it in a shared path folder.

Problem:
With snowflake, we discovered that running multiple SQL statements in a single worksheet is no longer an option.
The following options have been tried:

1. Run All in Snowflake worksheet
   By running all SQL statements using 'Run All' in snowflake worksheet returns only the latest query result in the Result grid.
2. Using snowSQL:
   Installed snowSQL and tried replicating the same thing as explained in 'Background' above.
   This worked well. But it works only in lower (tested in UAT env) environment because we don't have the access in PROD to perform the same.

So we need to brainstorm and find a solution for executing multiple SQL queries all in one shot in Prod

Any ideas?

Comment: It runs them all, but only shows the most recent in the results grid. Can you have each query update a table, and then your last query is a select * from that table?

Comment: @Isolated Actually in Prod, we don't have WRITE privileges, neither we have snowSQL in Prod. These are the blockers. 
Thinking of an out of the box solution for this.

Comment: And I take it you don't have another Database/Schema that you could write to? So you query from Prod and Write to another DB/Schema. That's what I do.

Comment: Can you use another client like dbeaver to submit and write out the files? That uses JDBC to connect. It's not clear why your snowsql attempt fails, so maybe jdbc connectios suffer the same issue?

Comment: Hi - why can’t you use SnowSql and connect to your Prod account? If you got the rights to run queries in the Prod UI you should be able to run them via SnowSQL

Comment: Can you create a stored procedure that can run in Prod that loops through the entire list of SQL statements, jams the results into a JSON string, and then gets output from the SP at the end of the run?  You'd have to query that JSON string afterwards, but that's easy.

Comment: hi @NickW
can't use because of policy, but sure that is one thing we are working on to get that access for Prod but for now it isn't there.

Comment: hi @JNevill
as the migration happened recently from oracle to snowflake, we currently are exploring the challenges and the way out. 
Currently we don't have another client like dbeaver as you suggested but I take it as something worth discussing and to further ask for. Thanks !

Comment: @Isolated
Exactly, we don't have another schema/ DB that we could write to in Prod. 
We are also considering this as an option to be asked for in Prod.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MikeWalton
I assume, stored procedure creation would be via Snowflake Scripting. But the only blocker again would be writing privileges in  Prod? 
But thanks for the comment,  I'll discuss with our DEV. If not exactly this solution, might open discussion for solution on similar lines.

Comment: @LV6001 are you saying that you can't create stored procedures and have those pushed into Prod for you?  Once the SP is created, you'd simply run it and get an output.  No writing.  Doesn't need to be Snowflake Scripting, either.  Any language would do.

Comment: Catching back up on this thread. Because you have very limited access within Snowflake, I don't think your solution should be aimed at Snowflake (stored procedure, temp tables, etc) and instead should be handled externally where you treat snowflake merely as a data repository. Python would make for a good language where you could login, execute your sql, and write out to CSV. DBeaver or similar thick clients, [which you could "install" as a portable app](https://portapps.io/app/dbeaver-portable/) to get around admin privilege lockout on your computer would likely suffice too.